# Maximum number of work that can be done in given two time slots [Double Knapsack?]

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, binary-search, knapsack-problem

An array A of size N denotes the number of hours required to produce `ith` object `(0 <= i < N)`. There are two factories that works for X and Y hours respectively.

Every object must be constructed using only one of these factories and only one object at a time can be produced on each factory .
Also, it is not possible to switch factories after starting the object's production.

What is the maximum number of **different** objects that can be produced in the factories.

Constraints:

`1 <= N, A[i] <= 1000`

`1 <= X, Y <= 500`

Example :

- A = [1,1,3] , X = 1 , Y = 1

  Answer should be 2 as objects at idx 0 and 1 will be constructed
- A = [6,5,5,4,3] , X = 8 , Y = 9

  Answer should be 4 as objects that requires 3 and 5 hrs will be produced in 1st factory and cars that require 4 and 5 will be produced in second factory.

  **What I have thought:**
- **Double Knapsack**

  Every object has 3 choices :

  1. To be produced in first factory
  2. To be produced in second factory
  3. Not produced at all

  So, try all possible options and see which option gives max number of objects.
  For this, I used  knapsack kind of approach

  ```
   dp[i][x][y] = max no. of objects that can be made using objects till index i in A array with x time remaining in first factory and y time remaining in second factory.

   Then dp[i][x][y] = max(dp[i-1][x-A[i]][y] + 1 , dp[i-1][x][y-A[i]] + 1, dp[i-1][x][y]).
   (with appropriate base cases which I'm not mentioning here).

   and the final ans will be just dp[N-1][X][Y]
  ```

  This will work but the time Complexity would be O(N*X*Y).

  In worst case N*X*Y = 1000* 500* 500 = 2.5*10^8 which will give TLE so it's not good enough.
- **Binary Search with DFS**

  I also thought of doing Binary search on the max number of objects that can be produced.

  And for each `mid` value in BS, check if it is possible to create that many object in X and Y time.

  But, for checking I will have to do a DFS or simply put consider putting the object in both the factory for each object.

  This checking step will give rise to 2^n time complexity itself.

  Or is there any better way to check(some greedy way maybe).

Or, Is there any better algorithm altogether to solve this?

Comment: This is at least as hard as the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), since that is a special case of your problem when X = Y = 1/2 sum(A). A modification of the pseudopolynomial DP algorithm should still fit your constraints to run in something closer to O(N(X+Y))

Comment: Are you sure the constraints are correct? It makes no sense for A[i] to be 1000, when X and Y are both limited to 500.

Comment: If you're looking for a guaranteed optimal solution, then I think that DP is the way to go. If you can settle for a heuristic method, you could try applying genetic algorithm which is a classical option for the knapsack problem. The obtained solution is not guaranteed to be optimal, but I think the complexity should be something like O(N×P×I) where P is the population size and I is the number of iterations, both configurable hyper-parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, this is an NP-hard problem, but only weakly NP-hard. A modification of your DP approach gives a pseudopolynomial time algorithm, running in time `O(n * min(X, Y) + n * log n)`, where the n log n comes from sorting the array.

First, note that since we're maximizing the number of items used, if we sort the array, we can just look for placements of the k smallest items for each k. We're only trying to find the first item we can't place.

Your DP algorithm only really needs two variables: the current item, and the capacity remaining in factory/bin X. We can figure out the capacity remaining in the other factory by subtracting from the total capacity used so far:

```c
dp[i][k] = True iff some valid partition of items A[0...i-1]
           leaves bin X with capacity exactly k

Let prefix_sum[i] be sum(A[0...i]).
Then after item i is placed, if we have capacity = k remaining in bin X,
we must have capacity = prefix_sum[i] - (X-k) being used in bin Y

Formula:
dp[i+1][k] = dp[i][k + A[i]] OR (dp[i][k] AND prefix_sum[i] - (X-k) <= Y)

This is valid for all 0 <= i <= n, 0 <= k <= X 
with all out-of-range values being False,
and base cases: dp[0][X] = True, dp[0][0...X-1] = False

The final answer will be the maximum i such that dp[i] is not all False.
```

---

For your constraints, this means our dp has at most 500,000 subproblems, which is solvable in much less than a second by an implementation like the following Python.

```py
def solve_dp(arr: List[int], X: int, Y: int) -> int:
    n = len(arr)
    arr.sort()

    # Ensure bin X is smaller than bin Y
    if X > Y:
        X, Y = Y, X

    # dp[k] = True iff some valid partition of all items processed so far
    # leaves bin X with capacity exactly k
    dp = [False] * (X + 1)
    dp[X] = True

    running_sum = 0

    for i, item_time in enumerate(arr):
        running_sum += item_time

        # Total extra capacity now allowed in both bins
        max_slack = X + Y - running_sum
        if max_slack < 0:
            return i

        # Largest extra capacity in bin X if we take this item
        first_item_cap = X - item_time

        upper_limit = min(X, max(max_slack, first_item_cap)) + 1
        for capacity in range(upper_limit):
            if capacity > max_slack:
                dp[capacity] = dp[capacity + item_time]
            elif capacity <= first_item_cap:
                dp[capacity] = dp[capacity] or dp[capacity + item_time]

        for capacity in range(upper_limit, X + 1):
            dp[capacity] = False

        if not any(dp):
            return i

    return n
```